# JInternalFrame alternative in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, swing, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an application in Swing that has free-floating `JInternalFrame`s. I am planning to move my application to Eclipse RCP. Are there any alternatives for that in Eclipse SWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may want to look at

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations
```

Read documentation for more SWT styles that it supports.

Example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setSize(600, 400);
    shell.setText("Decorations Example");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));

    Decorations d1 = new Decorations(shell, SWT.NO_TRIM);
    d1.setBackground(shell.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));

    Decorations d2 = new Decorations(shell, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
    d2.setText("dialog");

    Decorations d3 = new Decorations(shell, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    d3.setText("shell trim");

    Decorations d4 = new Decorations(shell, SWT.TOOL);
    d4.setText("tool");
    d4.setBackground(shell.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_YELLOW));
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Top level windows in SWT are always based on `Shell`.

For an Eclipse RCP you are not just restricted to the basic SWT controls, Eclipse provides many additional windows and dialogs built on top of SWT.

For a new Eclipse RCP you might want to look at the new `e4` style RCP. Here you specify the windows and menus in an application model which Eclipse will manage for you. For an introduction to this see [Eclipse 4 RCP - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html). This also gives you features such as CSS Styling and Direct Injection.